# Какие вершины у списка

Tags: python, numpy

Можно ли каким то простым способом определить количество вершин в списке **y** (в данном случае отдельно 5 верхних и 5 нижних)? **y** генерирую кодом ниже (**x** использовать не буду и на f = 5 не ориентироваться):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Fs = 800
f = 5
sample = 800
x = np.arange(sample)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * x / Fs)

plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Количество вершин - `f` верхних и `f` нижних. )

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Это вы узнали по коду f =, а вопрос в том как узнать если есть список только по котором можно построить график. Тоесть кол-во вершин изначально не известно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да вариантов на самом деле масса -  даже не используя collections.

Например:

Раз:

```
mxs = [i for i,ex in enumerate(y) if ex == y.max()]
print(len(mxs ))
```

Два:

```
print(np.sum(y==y.max()))
```

Три: - Обратим внимание на то, что тема вопроса "Какие вершины у **списка**", а в самом вопросе при этом фигурируют массивы numpy. И вернемся к теме, т.е. поиске в СПИСКЕ, то (первый оператор  -  просто возврат от массива к списку, т.е. сам ответ - во втором операторе):

```
y_l=list(y)
y_l.count(max(y_l))
```

Во всех случаях  ответ 5.

Для минимума, надеюсь, сможете по аналогии написать самостоятельно.

Comment: Идеальный ответ :)

Comment: Эмм.. проверка на точное равенство максимуму работает для сгенерированного указанным образом списка? И погрешности никогда не помешают?

Comment: @MBo я тоже об этом подумал. Но ТС именно так сформулировал задачу.   Будет другая формулировка -  будем думать как реализовать ее программно. Например -  при наличии погрешности максимумов будет чаще всего 1. А если учитывать погрешность -  будем сравнивать интервалы. Потребуются локальные максимумы -  применим соответствующий подход. Но пока -  строго по вопросу - тем более, что ответ ТС  вроде бы удовлетворил.

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов:

```py
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
    
#...

maximums = argrelextrema(y, np.greater)[0].size
minimums = argrelextrema(y, np.less)[0].size
```

Или вручную:

```
maximums = np.sum((y[1:-1] > y[:-2]) & (y[1:-1] > y[2:]))
minimums = np.sum((y[1:-1] < y[:-2]) & (y[1:-1] < y[2:]))
```